# Вертикальный текст в chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Доброго времени суток. Перерыл документацию по chart.js, но что-то не нашел, как заставить labels печататься вертикально?

Ситуация такая, что есть столбчатая диаграмма, столбиков штук 30, естественно все метки под столбиками не вмещаются и chart.js их НЕМНОГО поворачивает, и выводит скажем через 3. А мне надо, чтобы метка была под каждым столбцом, и располагалась вертикально... Это вообще легально, chart.js так умеет?

Answer (score 1):

Такое можно сделать. Достаточно установить три значения: maxRotation: 90, minRotation: 90, autoSkip: false в свойстве ticks определенной оси.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: chartData,
   options: {
   scales: {
   xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
      autoSkip: false,
      maxRotation: 90,
      minRotation: 90
      }
    }]
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все стало, как надо)